# insert ", " before 2nd occurrence of a particular word in string in unix

Tags: json, unix, awk, sed

I want to insert **", "** before every occurrence of a https, except first https in the below JSON

input:

```
https://gitlab.com/pc-sa/sa-pc-pcc/-/archive/test-demo/abc-test-demo.zip?path=Documentation Assets/temp check
https://gitlab.com/pc-sa/sa-pc-pcc/-/archive/test-demo/abc-test-demo.zip?path=Documentation Assets/temp dir
https://gitlab.com/pc-sa/sa-pc-pcc/-/archive/test-demo/abc-test-demo.zip?path=Documentation Assets/temp dir
```

Output:

```
https://gitlab.com/pc-sa/sa-pc-pcc/-/archive/test-demo/abc-test-demo.zip?path=Documentation Assets/temp check", "https://gitlab.com/pc-sa/sa-pc-pcc/-/archive/test-demo/abc-test-demo.zip?path=Documentation Assets/temp dir", "https://gitlab.com/pc-sa/sa-pc-pcc/-/archive/test-demo/abc-test-demo.zip?path=Documentation Assets/temp dir
```

EDIT: Adding OP's shown efforts(in comments) in post here.

```
cat /tmp/mmm.txt| sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/https/\","https/2'
```

Comment: This is not clear, please do add more details with clarity in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Have you tried anything in sed?

Comment: cat /tmp/mmm.txt| sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/https/\","https/2' but I don't know how many further https strings are there, I want to ignore first https string and for remaining nth https it should append ",".

Comment: What contains the string? Is it a file? Standard output of some command? Something else? Please show us your code, in the question itself.

Comment: @14MAR, Please add your efforts which you are mentioning in comments into your question, comments are not meant for code, kindly do so.

Comment: @14MAR, You have changed samples, these are not shown samples what you shown previously, it will be completely different question itself. So please put previous samples itself and open a new question for these samples.

Comment: @14MAR, Please don't change samples frequently else it will be a different question all together, I have also added your shown code in your post now, for new samples you can open new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following (written and tested with provided samples).

```
awk -v s1="\",\"" '{val=(val?val s1:"")$0} END{print val}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed level of explanation for above code.

```
awk -v s1="\",\"" '         ##Starting awk program here and creating variable s1 whose value is ","
{                           ##Starting this code main BLOCK from here.
  val=(val?val s1:"")$0     ##Creating variable val whose value is keep concatenating to its own value.
}                           ##Closing this program main BLOCK here.
END{                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print val                 ##Printing variable val here.
}                           ##Closing this program END block here.
'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

To save output into shell variable and read values from shell variable try like (where `var` is your shell variable having values, you could name it as per your wish):

```
var=$(echo "$var" | awk -v s1="\",\"" '{val=(val?val s1:"")$0} END{print val}'); echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change *all* occurrences, then change the first one *back:*

```
sed -e 's/https/", "https/g' -e 's/", "https/https/'
```

(Your examples don't quite match your description of the goal, so I can't test this solution but I think it's at least roughly correct.)

Comment: This will add in the first https as well, I don't want to do that. I want to exclude first https and for rest it should append ",".

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ORS=','}1' file
```

This will give you an extra comma at the end

```
 awk '{printf (FNR==1?"":",")"%s", $0}' file
```

This will not